# Python class attribut for data and refactoring

Tags: python

I do not find good advices regarding the followings question:
I'm creating a PyQt app and want persistent data in a single file per project (no serveur, no SQL).

I decided to create a class with attributes and then instanciate object. Then I store those objects in a list (expected < 500 objects and most project <60 objects). Finally I'm using kind of pickle module to store the data on a drive.

1. Is it a really bad things to do (class object is easier for me to understand than list of dict etc....)
2. I created the following the code

   `class Item:
       position = ['key','a','b','c']
       def__init__(self, key=None, a=None, b=None, c=None):
           self.key = key
           self.a = a
           self.b = b
           self.c = c`

   Is there a way to avoid repeating k,a,b,c (I might add lot of them later)

Comment: You shouldn't ask two totally unrelated questions in the same post.

Comment: "Then I store those objects in a list" : you understand that a `list` is not persistant ?

Comment: Yes , sorry for that I meant is it a bad idea to use list object for storing data rather than list of dict.

Comment: dicts are objects too... and actually objects are mainly dicts with some fancy features added. IOW it doesn't make a huge difference, except if you want to serialize your list to a file (you might have to add a bit of code to handle the serialization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Is there any good practice instead of storing a list of instances?

The ammount of data you specified is not very high, so a list of instances of a class should be doable but there are better ways to store this information.

1. List of `dict`, as you already said.
2. List of `namedtuple`s.

### Dict

#### Disguise a dict as an objetc

If you choose the first option, you could create a function that acts as a Class constructor to keep a similar syntax:

```
def Item(key=None, a=None, b=None, c=None):
    return {
        "key": key,
        "a": a,
        "b": b,
        "c": c
    }
```

#### An extra level of abstraction adds more flexibility

You could even create a function that generates this kind of function by passing a list of the keys:

```
def ItemGenerator(*spec):
    def f(*args, **kwargs):
        args = dict(enumerate(args))
        return {k: kwargs.get(k, args.get(i, None)) for i, k in enumerate(spec)}
    return f
```

The `ItemGenerator()` function accepts any number of strings as direct arguments, without needing to wrap them into a list. If you prefer to give just one list as an argument just remove the `*` from `def ItemGenerator(*spec):`. It creates a new function which returns a dictionary whose keys are the arguments passed to `ItemGenerator` and their values have `None` as default value. It would then be used like this:

> ***NOTE:** dicts in python are **unordered** so you may see the arguments in a different order while printing the results to the screen, but their value will be assigned correctly. I've listed them ordered for clearness.*

```
Item = ItemGenerator("key", "a", "b", "c")

# All default values
Item()                     # {"key": None, "a": None, "b": None, "c": None}
# Named and positional arguments
Item(a=1)                  # {"key": None, "a": 1,    "b": None, "c": None}
Item(1)                    # {"key": 1,    "a": None, "b": None, "c": None}
Item(key=1, a=2, b=3, c=4) # {"key": 1,    "a": 2,    "b": 3,    "c": 4   }
Item(1, 2, 3, 4, a=5)      # {"key": 1,    "a": 5,    "b": 3,    "c": 4   }
# Extra arguments
Item(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)        # {"key": 1,    "a": 2,    "b": 3,    "c": 4   }
Item(a=1, d=2)             # {"key": None, "a": 1,    "b": None, "c": None}
```

`Item` function is generated at the start by specifying the keys that the final dictionary will have and then can be used as many times as you want. When calling it, not providing one of the arguments specified to the generator sets its value to None. Both positional and named arguments can be used, but named ones take preference. Providing extra positional arguments or named arguments that were not in the specification omits them silently.

> **More technical description:** the generator is returning a function thats captures both positional and named (key-word) arguments, and converting the positional ones to a dict indexed by position in order to be able to use `dict.get(attrName, defaultValue)`. Then it uses a comprehension to return a dict whose keys are those defined in the generator and its values are first searched in the named arguments, secondly in the positional arguments and default to `None` if both of them are missing. The function generated is then being returned.

### Namedtuple

Instead of using a `dict` you could go for a `namedtuple` ([Python2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or [Python3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)) where you could use a similar aproach of making a function that returns the tuple or a function generator that returns a function that when called returns a namedtuple. It just changes the container.

## Can I assign attributes to a class automatically?

Yes, you can, as answered by others: [Iberê](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46604561/5612096) or [Vivek Pandey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46604576/5612096)

Comment: Hello. Nice sum-up of m'y underlying questions. Yes I'm interested in your Itemgenerator because I'd like toi be as much flexible as possible on these data.

Comment: @SylvainPage I've edited my answer to include the generator, tell me if you don't understand anything, but this should be pretty powerful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
class Item:
    position = ['key','a','b','c']
    def__init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key in Item.position:
            setattr(self,key,kwagrs.get(key, None))
```

This will make you class defition very hard to read though.

Answer (score 1):

1. No, it is not a bad thing to do
2. You can avoid reptition thus:

> ```
> class Item:
>     params = {}
>     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
>         self.params = kwargs
> ```

And now, you can do

```
item = Item(first_name='Sylvain', last_name='Page')
```

Comment: Nice ! and thanks for the answer, though liberê fits better my needs.